# error in storing captured images in a structure

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to capture 100 images from my webcam and then store them in a structure. I'm trying to do it like this but i'm getting the error, `'subscripted assignment dimensions mismatch'`.

The code is this:

```
sep_images=struct('images',[]);


vid=videoinput('winvideo',1,'YUY2_320x240');

set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',Inf);
set(vid,'ReturnedColorspace','rgb');

vid.FrameGrabInterval=1;

start(vid)


for num_frames= 1:100

    im=getsnapshot(vid);

   sep_images.images(num_frames)=im;

end

stop(vid);
```

and it is giving me the error in this statement, `sep_images.images(num_frames)=im;`.
If someone has the idea of how to do it? please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intended the `images` field to be a cell.

Initialize like:

```
sep_images=struct('images',{[]})
```

Assign like:

```
sep_images.images{num_frames}=im;
```

Just remember to access it with curly braces too (i.e. `I = sep_images.images{iframe}`).

Comment: thanks :)
i got the error what i was doing wrong.. :p

Comment: @user3801619 Great!  Please also up vote if you don't mind (up arrow above the number on the left).  :D